# How to use existing user and update schema with authentication threw passport.js

Tags: node.js, mongoose, passport.js

My goal:
For a patient to verify them self, then register the patient using passport.js by updating their already existing file.

My results:
I have it where the patient can be verified but when it goes to register for password and username passport creates a whole new patient object.

My code:

```
app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(session({
        secret:"secret",
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: false
    }));
    app.use(passport.session());
```

my local strategy:

```
passport.use(Patient.createStrategy());
passport.serializeUser((patient, done) =>{
    done(null, patient.id);
});
passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
    Patient.findById(id, (err, patient) => {
        done(err, patient);
    })
});
```

my schema:

```
const patientInfo = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String,
    accessCode: String,
    dateOfBirth: String,
    ssn: String,
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    contact: {
        address: {
            street: String,
            city: String,
            state: String,
            zip: Number
        },
        phone: String,
        email: String,
    },
    emergency: [{
        name: String,
        relation: String,
        phone: String
    }],
    records: {
        drNotes: [{
            type: String,        
            date: String,
            notes: String,
        vitals: {
            bpm: Number,
            o2: Number,
            bp: String,
            hieght: String,
            wieght: String
        }
        }],
        techNotes: [{
            type: String,
            date: String,
            notes: String,
            image: {
                data: Buffer,
                contentType: String
            }
        }],
        labs: [{
            type: String,
            date: String,
            results: String
        }],
        medications: [{
            type: String,
            quantity: Number,
            date: String
        }]}
});

patientInfo.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);
```

My Post Route:

```
app.post('/register', (req, res) => {
    let patientID = req.body.objID;

    Patient.register(({username: req.body.username}), req.body.password, (err, u) =>{
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }

        Patient.findByIdAndUpdate({username: req.body.username}, (err, patient) => {
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
            }

            passport.authenticate('local')(req,res, () =>{
                res.redirect('patient');
            });

        });
        
    });
```

Please Help!

Answer (score 0):

you can use [req.login](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/login/)

```
app.post('/register', (req, res,next) => {
    let patientID = req.body.objID;

    Patient.register(({username: req.body.username}), req.body.password, (err, u) =>{
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }

        Patient.findByIdAndUpdate({username: req.body.username}, (err, patient) => {
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
            }

            req.login(patient, function(error){
                if(error) {
                  return next(error);
                 }
                 res.redirect('patient');
            });
        });
    });
```